# JQuery touch enabled draggable sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I'm looking for a plugin / template for a sidebar that is touch enabled. I'd like users to be able to slide the sidebar left to hide it, and then slide it right (back in) to show it.

Does anyone know of such? If not, any pointers in the right direction as to how to implement this would also be much appreciated, im quite new to web dev.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using Slideout.js https://mango.github.io/slideout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using this one? http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Touch-Swipeable-Sidebar-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3.html